# 429 Too many request error despite using proxies

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using StormProxies to access Etsy data but despite using proxies and implementing retries I am getting `429 Too Many Requests` error most of the time(~80%+). Here is my code to access data:

```
import requests

def create_request(url, logging, headers={}, is_proxy=True):
    r = None
    try:
        proxies = {
            'http': 'http://{}'.format(PROXY_GATEWAY_IP),
            'https': 'http://{}'.format(PROXY_GATEWAY_IP),
        }

        with requests.Session() as s:
            retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504, 429])
            s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

            if is_proxy:
                r = s.get(url, proxies=proxies, timeout=30, headers=headers)
            else:
                r = s.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30)

            r.raise_for_status()

            if r.status_code != 200:
                print('Status Code = ', r.status_code)
                if logging is not None:
                    logging.info('Status Code = ' + str(r.status_code))
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception occur in create_request for the url:- {url}'.format())
        crash_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")
        crash_string = "".join(traceback.format_exception(etype=type(ex), value=ex, tb=ex.__traceback__))
        exception_string = '[' + crash_date + '] - ' + crash_string + '\n'
        print('Could not connect. Proxy issue or something else')
        print('==========================================================')
        print(exception_string)
    finally:
        return r
```

StormProxies guys say that I implement retries, this is how I have done but it is not working for me.

I am using Python `multiprocessing` and spawning 30+ threads at a time.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider accepting the limit they are setting, or possibly (if they allow it) pay them to raise the limit. Instead of trying to break it.

Comment: @Jorn Already 150 threads allocated.

Comment: ... that doesn't address what I wrote at all

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Comment: BTW: 150 threads is killer for everything, multitasking will generate huge overload

Comment: @JIST Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is, remove huge overhead based on thread management in one process (30+ is really lot).

It is more efficiency to use more processes with only a few threads (2-4 threads, based on delay with I/O) because threads in one process have to play with [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) (Global Interpreter Lock). In this case all will be only about configuration for your Python code.